# Comparate rows in 2 tables of a data mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

here is the thing.

Im doing a contest where ppl from my company can predict world cup matches.

for each game, they can choose a radio option, winner or a tie (options/values are 1,2,3).

Brasil  tie  Croacia

all these is stored in a table called "predictions" where is store an id, name, match1, match2, etc ...

then i have another table called "results" where i will store the right value for each match, after they play (ex. match1 = 1)

now i want to compare the match1 field from both tables, and if they match the user get a point.

did anybody did something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Don't store each match in a different column. They should be separate rows, where the match number is in the `match` column. Then you can write a join like this:

```
SELECT p.name, p.match, p.result = r.result AS correct
FROM predictions AS p
JOIN results AS r ON p.match = r.match
ORDER BY p.name, p.match
```

To get all of a person's points, you can aggregate:

```
SELECT p.name, SUM(p.result = r.result) AS points
FROM predictions AS p
JOIN results AS r ON p.match = r.match
GROUP BY p.name
ORDER BY p.name
```

To insert the predictions into the database, you use a loop:

```
foreach($_REQUEST['match'] AS $i => $match) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO mundial (nombre, match, p)
                 VALUES ('$_REQUEST[nombre]', $match, {$_REQUEST['p'][$i]})") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

The HTML for the prediction form should be like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="match[0]" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name="p[0]" value="1"> Brasil <input type="radio" name="p[0]" value="2"> Croacia <input type="radio" name="p[0]" value="3"> Tie
    <br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="match[1]" value="2">
    <input type="radio" name="p[1]" value="1"> Country3 <input type="radio" name="p[1]" value="2"> Country4 <input type="radio" name="p[1]" value="3"> Tie
    <br/>
    ... Repeat for each match
</form>
```

Comment: but how i will update the rows. because now i use: `mysql_query("insert into mundial(nombre,p1,p2,p3) values 
   ('$_REQUEST[nombre]',$_REQUEST[p1],$_REQUEST[p2],$_REQUEST[p3])", 
   $conexion) or die("Problemas en el select".mysql_error());` where p1,p2 are the names of the radios options: ex: `<input name="p2" type="radio" value="1"> México <input name="p2" type="radio" value="2"> tie <input name="p2" type="radio" value="3"> Camerún`  and now how do i update the rows in the way you say?

Comment: well .. i have some problem with the loop for the data base entry, its not working .. are you sure its ok ? i copied and replaced everything .. but its not working `<?php
$conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") 
  or die("Problemas en la conexion");
mysql_select_db("programa",$conexion) or
  die("Problemas en la seleccion de la base de datos");

 foreach($_REQUEST['match'] AS $i => $match) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO mundial (nombre, match, p)
                 VALUES ('$_REQUEST[nombre]', $match, {$_REQUEST['p'][$i]})");
}

   mysql_close($conexion);
echo "ok";
?>`

Comment: If you add `or die(mysql_error())` as shown in my updated answer, do you get an error?

Comment: Have you modified the table scheme to match what I said? The `mundial` table should have columns `nombre` VARCHAR, `match` INT, and `p` INT.

Comment: yes i modified, but now i have this error **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match, p) VALUES ('juan', 1, 1)' at line 1**

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize `match` is a reserved word. Either change the column name (translate it to Spanish?), or put it in backticks in the queries.

Comment: ok, i have to go now, tomorrow i will continue with this! thanks for the help

Comment: ok, now its working, at least the first part. The database its updated with the predictions. now i will try the comparison. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I would propose another approach: Use **rows instead of columns**, then `JOIN` with the 'results' table to get the score points for each user.

In the rows approach, the `predictions` table would consist of the columns: `id`, `match_id`, `match_guess`, so each user would contribute a few rows to that table, e.g. if user 123 guesses that match_1's result will be 2, this corresponds to the row `(123, 'match_1', 2)`.

The 'results' table would consist of the columns `match_id`, `match_result`, and then simply `JOIN` to calculate the points of each user e.g.

```
SELECT p.id, SUM(p.match_guess=r.match_result)
FROM predictions p, results r
WHERE p.match_id=r.match_id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: ok, it works, what if i want to add the sum to a new table where i have only the names and the points?